# How to insert data into table having nested table as one of its column

Tags: plsql

For example as below:
Col1 col2 col3(nestedtabletype)
100  101   A 100 sample 1998
A 101 sample 1999
A 102 sample 2000
101  102   B 100 sample 1998
B 101 sample 1111

Some thing like above col1,col2 are normal columns and column 3 is nested table type and May have more then one record as shown below.

Facing ora-21525 error when trying to achieve this by using custom object as input parameter to procedure